# how to make array of objects for grape

Tags: ruby, rest, parameters, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am building APIs using Grape Api for a rails application.

What I am trying right now is this form:[image]

And this is output:

```
{
    "page_score_master": {
        "issue_date": "2014-06-23"
    },
    "press_id": "1",
    "print_date": "2014-06-23",
    "product_id": 1,
    "pull_id": 2,
    "press_run_id": 1,
    "total_section": 1,
    "ssa": [
        {
            "ss": {
                "section_name": "A"
            },
            "ss1": {
                "section_name": "B"
            }
        }
    ],
    "foreman_id": 1,
    "pic_id": 1,
    "score_sheet_master_id": 1,
    "score_sheet_sections_attributes": {
        "score_sheet_id": "1"
    },
    "route_info": {
        "options": {
            "description": "create score sheet",
            "params": {
                "page_score_master": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "Hash"
                },
                "page_score_master[issue_date]": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "print_date": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "total_section": {
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "Integer"
                },
                "ssa": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "Array"
                },
                "ssa[section_name]": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "ssa[total_pages]": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "Integer"
                },
                "ssa[color_pages]": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "String"
                },
                "ssa[score_sheet_id]": {
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "Integer"
                }

    }
}
```

I have omitted some part of json to make it shorter.

What I need is to have an array or `ssa` but somehow unable to make it till now. It makes an array of `ssa` with only one object.

While in my API controller I have following code:

```
    optional :ssa, type: Array do
      requires :ss, type: Hash do
        optional :section_name, type: String
        optional :total_pages, type: Integer
        optional :color_pages, type: String
        optional :score_sheet_id, type: Integer
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you have 2 problems here.
First one lies in you form declaration.
In the code you say you have an Array (called `ssa`) of Hashes (called `ss`).
In your form, you're sending a hash called `ss1` as part of your 'ssa' Array. The `ss1` hash will be ignored, thus you'll only have one 'ss' element in you array.

If you rename the `ss1` into `ss` in your form:

```
ssa[][ss][section_name]   A
ssa[][ss][section_name]   B
```

you'll get to the second problem, which lies in the API controller definition:

Your controller expects a 'ssa' array that can only have one 'ss' hash element. Thus it will overwrite the first `[ss][section_name]`.

What you want to do is declare the `ssa` as a an Array and remove the `ss` group:

```
requires :ssa, type: Array do
    optional :section_name, type: String
    optional :total_pages, type: Integer
    optional :color_pages, type: String
    optional :score_sheet_id, type: Integer
end
```

This will require an array (`ssa`) of hashes. You don't need to declare the `ss` group, it already expects an array of hashes  with `section_name`, `total_pages`, etc. as keys. If `ssa` is not a required param, simply declare it `optional`, as you did in your controller.
Then, your form should look like this:

```
ssa[][section_name]                ABC
opportunity[ssa][][total_pages]    3
ssa[][section_name]                DEF
opportunity[ssa][][total_pages]    6
```

This will result in:

```
:ssa=>
  [{:section_name=>"DEF",
    :total_pages=>3,
    :color_pages=>nil,
    :score_sheet_id=>nil},
   {:section_name=>"HGJK",
    :total_pages=>6,
    :color_pages=>nil,
    :score_sheet_id=>nil}]
```

Comment: Have you ever try this?